# How to make this await work in a setinterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function call inside an async function

```
let productoCatalogo = await this.getCatalogoCard(codigoProducto)
```

And it calls

```
    getCatalogoCard = (codProduct: string) => {
        this.setState({ isLoadCatalogoCard: false })
    
        if (!localStorage.getItem("SS_CATALOGOS")) {
          this.props.getCatalogo()
        }
    
        let time = setInterval(() => {
          if (localStorage.getItem("SS_CATALOGOS")) {
            clearInterval(time);
            let res: any = localStorage.getItem("SS_CATALOGOS")
            res ? (res = JSON.parse(res)) : (res = [])
            let catalogo: any = localStorage.getItem("SS_CATALOGOS") && res.filter(catalogo => catalogo.codProducto === codProduct)
            if(catalogo){
              this.setState({ isLoadCatalogoCard: true })
              //the return
return { current: catalogo.precioNeto, old: catalogo.precioTarifa }
            }
          }
        }, 250)
      }
```

I have written the following code but it doesnt seem to work.

I understand that maybe setting up a promise would fix this, but i dont understand how to do so

Comment: What does `props.getCatalogo` do and what does it return?

Comment: @trincot it feeds the localstorage, it doesnt return anything. It sets the localStorage element SS_CATALOGOS

Comment: Does it do it synchronously?

Comment: @trincot no , its an api call

Comment: I understand it is an API call, but an API call can be synchronous or asynchronous. If it is asynchronous, why does it not provide a promise, a callback, or an event listener? Every asynchronous API provides one way or another to get informed about the completion of the job.

Comment: Like @trincot says, you should not need to poll the localstorage, the `getCatalogo` function should notify you about the completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new promise and wait for it instead of using a callback:

```
getCatalogoCard = async (codProduct: string) => {
  ... 
  
  // wait 250ms if condition is not true
  await new Promise((res, rej) => {
        let time = setInterval(() => {
            if (localStorage.getItem("SS_CATALOGOS")) {
               clearinterval(time);
               res();
            }
        },1000);
  })

  ... // everything after condition passed

}
```